# HashMap#entrySet throwing ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

```
// channels is a HashMap<String,Channel>
for (Channel channel : channels.entrySet().toArray(new Channel[channels.entrySet().size()])) {
    // stuff
}
```

throws ArrayStoreException. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`entrySet()` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`, so you can't produce a `Channel` array from it.

You don't really need to create an array in order to iterate of the `Channel` values. Just use `values()` :

```
for (Channel channel : channels.values()) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: So how would I convert that?

Comment: @Priv Is Channel the key of the Map?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the documentation of ArrayStoreException? It says “Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.” So the obvious (and likely :-) guess is `toArray()` is trying to store something into your `Channel` array that is not a `Channel`. That makes sense, since the entry set consists, not of `Channel` objects, but of `Map.Entry<String,Channel>`. Those are not the same.